# Field extension generated by coefficients of minimum polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

The question goes as follows:
Let $K\subset E\subset K(\alpha)$ be a tower of field extensions, with $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$. Prove that as an extension of $K$, the field $E$ is generated by the coefficients of the minimum polynomial $f^\alpha_E\in E[X]$.

I have had the following idea, using a previous result:
Let $K\subset K(\alpha)$ be a simple extension of degree $n$, and define $c_i\in L$ by

$$ \sum^{n-1}_{i=0} c_i X^i=\frac{f^\alpha_K}{X-\alpha}\in L[X]$$

Then $\{ c_0,c_1,…,c_{n-1}\}$ is a $K$-basis for $L$.

I think this result could be used to prove the statement above, but I am not sure how I could adapt it to the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Call $L$ the field generated by the coefficients. Then look at the degree of extensions.

Comment: I don’t quite get it. How can I infer something about the degree of that extension?

Answer (score 2):

We have the extensions $K \subset E \subset K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$. Therefore, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $E$. We write $f^{\alpha}_E := \sum^n_{k=0} a_k x^k \in E[x]$ and $L:= K(a_0,...,a_n)$. Because $E \subset K(\alpha)$, we see that $E(\alpha) \subset L(\alpha)=: K(a_0,...,a_n)(\alpha)$. However, because $L \subset E$, we also know that $L(\alpha) \subset E(\alpha)$. So, we get that $L(\alpha) = E(\alpha)$.

Let's look at the tower $L \subset E \subset E(\alpha) = L(\alpha)$. We denote by $f^{\alpha}_E$ resp. $f^{\alpha}_L$ the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E$ resp. $L$. Notice that $f^{\alpha}_L \in E[x]$, thus $f^{\alpha}_E \mid f^{\alpha}_L$.

Furthermore, $f^{\alpha}_E \in L[x]$, because $L$ is generated by the coefficients of $f^{\alpha}_E$. Thus, $f^{\alpha}_L \mid f^{\alpha}_E$ as well. Now, we can see that $f^{\alpha}_E = f^{\alpha}_L$, therefore $[ L(\alpha) :L] = [E(\alpha):E]$, and we can conclude that $[E:L] = 1$. In other words, $L = E$.